# This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.it requires “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription”

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

this error occurs

> This app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a
>   usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” key with a string value
>   explaining to the user how the app uses this data

even though i have added "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" on an iOS 13 device.do i still need “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription”. i guess "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" should handle all the requirements.

Comment: No, you need both. Earlier versions of iOS don’t n ow about the new key, so you need the old one as well

Comment: but i am running it on iOS 13. and i have added both   Privacy - Location Always Usage Description     and  Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description  ...

Comment: i want the app to ask for "allow always" permission but is doesn't.

Comment: If you wan't "Always" then you need to include `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` - You are running iOS 13 but other people running your app may not be, so you need to include the old key and the new key.

Comment: i have added both keys sir but it still gives error of NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription.in your opinion what else could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have all three keys?

Comment: i have both  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription    and   NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription . when i add third key it requests for location for once only or while using the app. i want to get always permission.

Comment: You need all three.  In iOS 13 when you ask for "Always" the user initially sees only a prompt for "when in use".  If they allow when in use then you receive provisional "always" access, but you only receive location when in use.  After some time of using location in the background the user will be prompted to upgrade to "Always", keep with "when in use" or remove your app's access.  The user can use settings to change your access to "always" at any time.  You should watch the WWDC video on location in iOS 13 to understand how it works now.

Comment: okay thanks but its so irritating...

Comment: It’s actually a great improvement to help users make a decision about whether they really want to give always permission to an app